# Testing Marionette View and Handlebars template with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jasmine, handlebars.js, marionette

I am trying to test a backbone application.
When I need to test a simple backbone.view I have no problem.
If I need to test a Backbone View made by using `Backbone.Marionette` (ItemView or CompositeView) and `Handlebars template` I get the following message:

```
NoTemplateError: Could not find template: 
function(context, options) {
    if (!compiled) {
      compiled = compile();
    }
    return compiled.call(this, context, options);
  };
```

The code about `function(context, options)` comes from `handlebars-1.0.0.beta.6.js`.
Any idea how to fix the code?

Here the test which I am performing:

```
describe("AppViewMarionette", function() {
    beforeEach(function(){
        this.view = new AppViewMarionette();

    });

    describe("Rendering", function () {

        it("returns the view object", function () {
            expect(this.view.render()).toEqual(this.view);
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: what version of Marionette are you using?

Comment: Hi @DerickBailey. I am using `Backbone.Marionette v0.9.1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update your version of Marionette. v0.9.1 doesn't support pre-compiled templates being directly assigned to the `template` setting. You need v0.9.7 or higher for that.

If you can't update, you'll need to follow these instructions to get it working: https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette/wiki/Using-pre-compiled-templates